# Sum n values in sparse dataset

Tags: excel

I have a sparse dataset in excel, e.g.:

1 0 2 4 5 8

2 3 0 0 0 6

Zeros represent missing values.

I want to sum the first 3 nonmissing values in each row using Excel.

Thanks

Comment: most aggregate Excel functions like SUM and AVERAGE ignore non-numeric values, sou you can just SUM the entire row range

Comment: But I only want the first 3 values in each row.

Comment: sorry didn't read the question carefully. Seems like it will be a tricky array formula

Answer (score 3):

For a sum against EACH row, you can do as below:

Array formula - use:

> Ctrl+Shift+Enter

`=SUM(INDEX($A1:$F1, 1, 1):INDEX($A1:$F1, 1, SMALL(IF($A1:$F1, COLUMN($A1:$F1) - COLUMN($A1) + 1), 3)))`

[image]
Image shows second row selected, but formula I typed  shows first row.

Answer (score 3):

For a normally entered formula, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(A1,0,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(A1:K1<>0)*COLUMN(A1:K1),{1,2,3})-1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Excel at home to test it, but you can try entering this formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1:F1,0,0,1,SMALL(IF(A1:F1,COLUMN(A1:F1)),3)))
```

The `SMALL(IF(A1:F1>"",COLUMN(A1:F1)),3)` part should return the index of the third non-zero cell.

Comment: thanks @MacroMarc not quite sure if the cells are 0 or blank

Comment: Actually, `IF(A1:F1,...`  will evaluate to `FALSE` if the cells contain `0` or are blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of Excel 2016 and you know for sure that each cell will only contain one digit, you can leverage the CONCAT Function:

```
=SUM(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:F1),0,""),{1,2,3},1))
```